# Как разделить api на составляющие в разных .py файлах при использовании flask?

Tags: python, flask

Хочу разделить api на составляющие в разных .py файлах, например регистрация и авторизация в одном файле, сохранение изображений в другом, для этого я так понимаю нужно использовать классы, сейчас у меня все в одном файле, выглядит это таким образом:

```
1.py

# импорты наверху

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


def connect_db():
    return pymysql.connect(
        host="****",
        user="****",
        password="****",
        database="****",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )


def get_db():
    '''Opens a new database connection per request.'''
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = connect_db()
    return g.db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    '''Closes the database connection at the end of request.'''
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()

@app.route('/autorization', methods=['POST'])
def autorization():
    # код
   





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Нужно чтоб в файле 2.py я мог написать функции и файлы 1.py, 2.py работали единовременно как один

```
2.py

from 1 import * 

@app.route("/profile", methods=['POST'])
def profile():
```

Что-типа такого, пробовал задавать классы, но слетало с ошибкой, в общем хочу разобраться.

Comment: Имена модулей не могут начинаться на цифру

Comment: Это для примера